# ANTLR 4 token rule that matches any characters until it encounters XYZ

Tags: antlr, grammar, tokenize, antlr4, lexical-analysis

I want a token rule that gobbles up all characters until it gets to the characters `XYZ`.

Thus, if the input is this:

```
helloXYZ
```

then the token rule should return this token:

```
hello
```

If the input is this:

```
Blah Blah XYZ
```

then the token rule should return this token:

```
Blah Blah
```

How do I define a token rule to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the hint that Terrance gives in his answer, I think this is what Roger is looking for:

```
grammar UseLookahead;

parserRule : LexerRule;

LexerRule : .+? { (_input.LA(1) == 'X') &&
                  (_input.LA(2) == 'Y') &&
                  (_input.LA(3) == 'Z') 
                }?
          ;
```

This gives the answers required, `hello` and `Blah Blah` respectively.  I confess that I don't understand the significance of the final `?`.

Comment: The `{...}?` syntax is called a semantic predicate.  See ch 11.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
HELLO : 'hello' {_input.LA(1)!=' '}? ;
```

Comment: But this isn't looking for `XYZ`.  It's looking for not-space.  That's not the same, right?

Comment: BTW, where is the LA() method documented?  I can't find it in the ANTLR book.

Comment: I too could not find the LA() method in the ANTLR book.

Comment: Is it this?  http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/index.html?org/antlr/v4/runtime/IntStream.html  But it returns an int. Hmm.

Answer (score 1):

If you want good performance, you need to use a form which does not use predicates. I would use code modeled after [PositionAdjustingLexer.g4](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/tool/test/org/antlr/v4/test/tool/PositionAdjustingLexer.g4) to reset the position if the token ends with `XYZ`.

**Edit:** Don't underestimate the performance hit of the answer using a semantic predicate. The predicate will be evaluated at least once for every character of your entire input stream, and any character where a predicate is evaluated is prevented from using the DFA. The last time I saw something like this in use, it was responsible for more than 95% of the execution time of the entire parsing process, and removing it improved performance from more 20 seconds to less than 1 second.

```
tokens {
  SpecialToken
}

mode SpecialTokenMode;

  // In your position adjusting lexer, if you see a token with the type
  // SpecialTokenWithXYZ, reset the position to remove the last 3 characters and set
  // the type to SpecialToken
  SpecialTokenWithXYZ
    : 'XYZ'
      -> popMode
    ;

  SpecialTokenCharacterAtEOF
    : . EOF
      -> type(SpecialToken), popMode
    ;

  SpecialTokenCharacter
    : .
      -> more
    ;
```

If you want *even better* performance, you can add a couple rules to optimize handling of sequences that do not contain any `X` characters:

```
tokens {
  SpecialToken
}

mode SpecialTokenMode;

  // In your position adjusting lexer, if you see a token with the type
  // SpecialTokenWithXYZ, reset the position to remove the last 3 characters and set
  // the type to SpecialToken
  SpecialTokenWithXYZ
    : 'XYZ'
      -> popMode
    ;

  SpecialTokenCharacterSpanAtEOF
    : ~'X'+ EOF
      -> type(SpecialToken), popMode
    ;

  SpecialTokenCharacterSpan
    : ~'X'+
      -> more
    ;

  SpecialTokenXAtEOF
    : 'X' EOF
      -> type(SpecialToken), popMode
    ;

  SpecialTokenX
    : 'X'
      -> more
    ;
```