# About semantic predicate in ANTLR 4

Tags: antlr4

In this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28074334/5973816, The answerer said that the following grammar can match the text ending with XYZ and does not contain XYZ, but I found that it can't, what should the correct grammar be?

```
grammar UseLookahead;

parserRule : LexerRule;

LexerRule : .+? { (_input.LA(1) == 'X') &&
                  (_input.LA(2) == 'Y') &&
                  (_input.LA(3) == 'Z') 
                }?
          ;
```

I tested locally and found that 'Blah Blah XYZ' only matches 'B'.

Comment: How did you test it? You cannot test it with the IntelliJ plugin for example, because it does not evaluate embedded code/predicates. Please edit your question and include the code you used to test it.

Comment: @BartKiers Ah? I use the IntelliJ plugin for visual testing. It turns out that the plugin does not support this feature. I will write a code to test it, thank you.

Comment: Sure, no problem. I also did a quick test, and the grammar seems to do what you expect (see my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I test your grammar with the following Java code:

```java
String source = "Blah Blah XYZ";

UseLookaheadLexer lexer = new UseLookaheadLexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));
CommonTokenStream stream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
stream.fill();

for (Token t : stream.getTokens()) {
  System.out.printf("%-35s `%s`%n",
      UseLookaheadLexer.VOCABULARY.getSymbolicName(t.getType()),
      t.getText().replace("\n", "\\n"));
}
```

the following is printed:

```
LexerRule                           `Blah Blah `
EOF                                 `<EOF>`
```

as well as the following warning on stderr:

```
line 1:10 token recognition error at: 'XYZ'
```